# Comparing String with equals() does not work

Tags: java, string, compare, equals

I have a `jtable` and an array of objects. In my code i save the jtable's row values in this array using a `for` loop and `getValueAt()`. The problem is when i compare a value of this array with the string literal using `equals()`, it returns `false` although the values are same.

Below is the code where i fill the array:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                JTable target = (JTable) e.getSource();

                if ((target.getSelectedRow() >= 0)
                        && (target.getSelectedColumn() >= 0)) {

                    invoiceRow = target.getSelectedRow();
                    invoiceCol = target.getModel().getColumnCount();
                    invoiceId = (BigDecimal) returnedInvoiceTable
                            .getModel().getValueAt(invoiceRow, 0);
                Object []   invoiceRowData = new Object[invoiceCol];

                    for (int i = 0; i < invoiceCol; i++) {
                        invoiceRowData[i] = returnedInvoiceTable.getModel()
                                .getValueAt(invoiceRow, i);

                    }

                    fillReturned();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

and this is the code where i compare a value from the array with the string literal

```
if (invoiceRowData[8].toString().equals("immediate")) {

}
```

this returns `false` although the two values are the same, And when i print the `invoiceRowData[8].toString()` it prints `immediate`.

what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you try trimming before compare.

Comment: please show your `toString()` method for whatever object is stored in invoiceRowData.

Comment: now it works with trim() although i checked the string and found it has no spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... this returns false although the two values are the same.

It seems strange that you would be the first person on the planet to find this bug, among the millions that use `equals()` every day :-)

Far more likely it is, young padawan, that you've made a mistake somewhere, and they're *not* actually identical.

This could be caused by numerous things, such as case, non-Latin characters that look very similar to their Latin counterparts, or spaces at one end of the string or the other.

If you *really* want to know if they're different, try the following:

- Print out the lengths.
- For each substring at the start (first character, first two characters, and so on), compare the equivalent parts of the two strings.

If the lengths are not identical, it probably involves spaces. In that case, you'd probably look into using [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) to clean it up before comparison.

If you find a substring that doesn't match, then have found the character causing the problem, and you can get the code point of each with something like [`String.codePointAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt%28int%29).